# How to get HTML table with header data from database and row data from database as well in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working in mvc project where I want to generate one gridview(html table). The headers should bind from db and data also should bind from db dynamically. 
This is my metadata or master table.

```
Id      Name    Label           Value         Emp_id
31      Adhar   DocumentNumber  12345678       1
32      Adhar   ExpiryDate      1/1/2015       1
33      Pan     DocumentNumber  123456789      2
34      Pan     ExpiryDate      1/1/2015       2
36      Pan     IssueLoc        India          2
```

and my table should be like this below. if the input parameter emp_id is 1 then table should look like below. This is HTML

```
<Table><tr><th>DocumentNumber</th><th>ExpiryDate</th><td>12345678       </td>1/1/2015<td></td></tr></table>
```

OR
this is plain web sheet.

```
DocumentNumber   ExpiryDate
12345678         1/1/2015
```

I am working in mvc4 entity framework. How to overcome from this? Can anybody give me some idea to solve it. I have googed across and found nothing. Please provide me some idea. If question is uncleared please let me know

This is for emp_id with 2

```
DocumentNumber   ExpiryDate  IssueLoc
12345678         1/1/2015    India
```

With respect to above data I need output in the form of

```
    Name   DocumentNumber   ExpiryDate
    Adhar  12345678         1/1/2015
    Name   DocumentNumber   ExpiryDate  IssuedLoc
    Pan    123456789        1/1/2015    India
```

Yes, The answer you provided is almost correct as per my requirement. I tried myself to make table as I need but I could not get it. Sorry for troubling you

Comment: What should be, if sets of Labels are same for all items, should headers repeated or only one top header is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group your data by the `Name` and then create a separate table for each group. To make this easier, add another view model

```
public class GroupVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller method

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var table = new List<MyItem> {
        new MyItem { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "12345678", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new MyItem { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "1/1/2015", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new MyItem { Label = "IssueLoc", Value = "India", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new MyItem { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "SecondValue", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" },
        new MyItem { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "SecondValue", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" },                
    };
    var data = table.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new GroupVM
    {
        Name = x.Key,
        Items = x
    });
    return View(data);
}
```

and then in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<GroupVM>
@foreach(var group in Model)
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                @foreach(var item in group.Items)
                {
                    <th>@item.Label</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@group.Name</td>
                @foreach(var item in group.Items)
                {
                    <td>@item.Value</td>
                }
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Refer [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rdfRkX)

Comment: Great Logic. This is what i need. thanks Stephen. You are helping me from long time. Thanks a lot

Comment: You seem to have another [related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773476/render-header-fields-as-per-database-data) which should be deleted assuming this answer also solves that.

Comment: Also, when you get an answer that helps you, up vote, but don't actually accept it unless it solves you issue - it just confuses other users)

Comment: okay sure. up Vote I did not know it. I tried your answer its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vi4q7z) will be look like this:

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    //Here I mock your DB, use EF context (context.table) instead of table variable or what you want.
    var table = new List<MyItem> {
        new MyItem { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "12345678", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new MyItem { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "1/1/2015", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },
        new MyItem { Label = "IssueLoc", Value = "India", Emp_id = 1, Name = "First" },

        new MyItem { Label = "DocumentNumber", Value = "SecondValue", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" },
        new MyItem { Label = "ExpiryDate", Value = "SecondValue", Emp_id = 2, Name = "Second" },                
    };

    var items = table.Where(x => x.Emp_id == 1 || x.Emp_id == 2).ToList();
    var headers = items.Select(x => x.Label).Distinct().ToList();
    var employers = items.Select(x => x.Emp_id).Distinct().ToList();

    if(employers.Count > 1)
        headers.Insert(0, "Name");

    var data = new List<List<string>>();
    data.Add(headers);            

    foreach (var emp in employers)
    {
        var row = new List<string>();
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {                    
            if (header != "Name")
            {
                var cell = items.Where(x => x.Label == header && x.Emp_id == emp).FirstOrDefault();
                row.Add(cell == null ? "" : cell.Value);
            }                        
            else
                row.Add(items.Where(x => x.Emp_id == emp).First().Name);
        }
        data.Add(row);
    }

    return View(data);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model List<List<string>>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var header in Model.First())
            {
                <th>@header</th>
            }
        </tr>        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in Model.Skip(1))
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var cell in row)
                {
                    <td>@cell</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes exactly but for emp_id there are 3 fields so how to get third column? I just shown in question(edited main question)

Comment: Yes exactly but for emp_id there are 3 fields so how to get third column? I just shown in question(edited main question) Based on emp_id if there are 2 fields I want to display only two fields(for example, emp_id with 1 contains 2 fields) and if there are 3 fields I want to display three fields(e.g emp_id with 2) and final case is if I pass two both emp_id 's then I want to display all details(e.g Adhar and Pan with respect to above table).

Comment: My solution not depends on concrete fields or their count, it is flexible and universal. Look at edited answer, I just add new element to table variable collection.

Comment: Yes I will study the solution. Thanks a lot Slava. If any doubts I get can I ask you?

Comment: Hi Slava, May I know what is Model.First and Model.Skip. Do I need to create any view model?

Comment: With considering of all your comments I edit my answer. Now it works as you desired: it shows names of items and only specified properties, if one item has property and another not - this one will be blank.

Comment: And answering on your comment: skip() and take() now not actual. You should only create class MyItem with properties corresponding to your master table, but I guess, that you already have it. And you dont need to create any ViewModel, because it is not custom, it is simple List<List<string>>, look more carefully at View section of my answer.